# If $Y$ is closed subspace of $(X,\|\cdot\|)$, then subspace $<Y\cup \{x_0\}>$ is closed in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space and $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$, such that $Y\neq X.$ If $x_0\in X\setminus Y,$ prove that the subspace $<Y\cup \{x_0\}>$ is closed in $X$.

**Attempt.** Let $x\in X$ be in the closure of $<Y\cup \{x_0\}>$, so $y_n+\lambda_nx_0\rightarrow x$ for some $(y_n)$ in $Y$ and $(\lambda_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}.$

*Claim 1.* $(\lambda_n)$ is Cauchy. Then 
$\lambda_n$ converges to some $\lambda$ and $$y_n=y_n+\lambda_nx_0-\lambda_nx_0\rightarrow x-\lambda x_0$$
so $x=(x-\lambda x_0)+\lambda x_0\in <Y\cup \{x_0\}>$.

or

*Claim 2*. $(\lambda_n)$ is bounded. Then some subsequence $(\lambda_{k_n})$ converges to some $\lambda$ and $$y_{k_n}=y_{k_n}+\lambda_{k_n}x_0-\lambda_{k_n}x_0\rightarrow x-\lambda x_0$$
so $x=(x-\lambda x_0)+\lambda x_0\in <Y\cup \{x_0\}>$.

I am not sure which one of the above claims is correct (if so) and I can't prove either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since$Y$ is closed,  $X/Y$ is a normed space and the quotient map $\pi : X      \to X/Y$ is continuous.  Does this help?

Comment: If $\lambda_n$ were unbounded, you could arrange, by passing to a subsequence, that $\lambda_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Then, for large $n$, you'd have that $\frac{y_n}{\lambda_n}+x_0$ is very close to $\frac x{\lambda_n}$, which in turn is very close to $0$. So the sequence of points $\frac{y_n}{\lambda_n}$ from $Y$ would converge to $-x_0$.  That's a contradiction, since $Y$ is closed and doesn't contain $x_0$.